# Tab complete in VI mode KSH 'vi-tabcomplete' gives bad options

Tags: vi, ksh

When I try stuff like in my .profile:

```
set -o vi-tabcomplete
```

I get:

```
.profile[292]: vi-tabcomplete: bad option(s)
```

Does anyone know of a workaround?

Answer (score 2):

It depends which flavour of ksh you have.

Older pre-ksh-93 shells support 'double-escape' auto complete - so you hit 
<kbd>Esc</kbd> twice instead of <kbd>Tab</kbd> once.

ksh-93 uses `set -o viraw` to enable tab completion.

Public-domain ksh, [pdksh](http://web.cs.mun.ca/~michael/pdksh/) which you may be able to obtain and use if your environment permits, is the one that supports the `set -o vi-tabcomplete` syntax.  It also supports `set -o vi-esccomplete` for compatibility with older ksh variants.

Answer (score 0):

In Fedora 11's ksh, you get tab completion after just `set -o vi`

```
$ echo KSH_VERSION
Version M 93t 2008-11-04
$ rpm -q -a | grep ksh
ksh-20081104-3.fc11.i586
```